# MS Graph API: microsoft.graph.createLink not creating anonymous view links

Tags: onedrive, microsoft-graph-api

I'm using graph API to iterate over a folder in OneDrive for Business.  I'm attempting to generate "anonymous view" links for each item in the folder using the following call:

`/v1.0/users('user-guid')/drive/items/item-id/microsoft.graph.createLink`

with the body:

```js
{
   "type": "view",
   "scope": "anonymous"
}
```

This works correctly for items that have already been given the "View link- no sign-in required" permission via the OneDrive UI. However, executing this call against an item that doesn't have this sharing option already set, results in the following return message:

```js
{
  "error": {
    "code": "unauthenticated",
    "message": "The caller is not authenticated.",
    "innerError": {
    "request-id": "1c3600ec-4861-4be4-9a7b-74264f488a80",
    "date": "2016-03-13T02:30:10"
    }
  }
}
```

I know that this is not an authentication issue because my token works fine for all other calls (and calls against items that already have their file sharing set).  I get the same behavior from the [Microsoft Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) tool.  If I manually set the "View link - no sign-in required" permission in OneDrive this call executes perfectly.  My credentials for the API call are the same credentials I'm using to set the permissions in the OneDrive UI.

The documentation for [microsoft.graph.createLink](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/item_createlink) states

> The createLink method will create a new sharing link if the specified link type doesn't already exist. If a sharing link of the specified type already exists for the app, the existing sharing link will be returned.

Any ideas what's going wrong here?

Comment: Did you resolve this? We have the same problem described in this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42439078/ms-graph-daemon-app-401-unauthorized-on-files-readwrite-all-calls

Answer (score 0):

The `url` should be simply `/createLink` (without the `microsoft.graph` prefix):

`POST /me/drive/items/{item-id}/createLink`